# Visual C++: creating a dll using libcurl

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, dll, libcurl

I'm developing dll that uses libcurl. After adding `libcurl.dll` and `libidn-11.dll` to dependences I get `libcurl.dll : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x308`.

PS: I'm using MSVS 2010

PPS: I'd successfully compiled that dll with mingw compiler, no problems were thrown there.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: why are you compiling curl and your project with different compilers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is there a `libcurl.lib` to accompany `libcurl.dll`? You're meant to link with the `lib` file, not the `dll` directly.

Answer (score 3):

In the Windows world, access to dynamic libraries is usually done through a small static library (.lib) stub.

In VS, you'd then link against the .lib file, which contains the code necessary to load the dll at runtime.

You can't link directly against the .dll.

If you're used to Linux, this probably seems like a somewhat awkward way of doing it, but that's how it is.

So, do you have such a .lib file for your curl library? If so, link against that. If not, using curl from your VS project is going to be a bit more work. (But one option might be to just build curl with VS, which'd give you both .dll and .lib file)

Comment: Fwiw, the import library doesn't contain any code to load the DLL.  It is merely a list of exported names.  It is pretty routine in Windows to have exported names that are different from the compiler generated name, all of the operating system DLLs are like that for example.  To make GetProcAddress() easy to use.  And to allow name decoration to catch declaration errors that would destabilize the program badly.

Comment: Fair enough. :) I've never really looked at what's actually in the import library.